# Java SimpleDateFormat pattern for W3C XML dates with timezone

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, iso8601

I am trying to parse a [W3C](http://www.w3c.org) XML Schema date like the following

```
"2012-05-15T07:08:09+03:00"
```

which complies with the ISO 8601 version of the [W3C XML Schema dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) specification.

In the above date, the timezone identifier is `"+03:00"`, but no `SimpleDateFormat` pattern apparently exists to represent it.

If the timezone were `"+0300"`, then `Z` (uppercase) would be applicable and the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern would be

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

Similarly, if the timezone were `"GMT+03:00"`, then `z` (lowercase) would be applicable and the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern would be

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz
```

(uppercase `'Z'` also works, by the way).

So, is there a `SimpleDateFormat` pattern or workaround to represent the above date without preprocessing of the date string?

Comment: Actually, that input string is in a format from the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard (a family of date-time formats).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about something like:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"){ 
    public Date parse(String source,ParsePosition pos) {    
        return super.parse(source.replaceFirst(":(?=[0-9]{2}$)",""),pos);
    }
};
```

Comment: Clever, elegant and functional. Thanks!

Comment: Whoever needs to use the ParsePosition after parse() returns, you may need to adjust the index by one inside parse(), since the source is actually 1 longer, i.e. do something like pos.setIndex(pos.getIndex()+1).

Comment: changed to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` and it worked like a charm for miliseconds too

Answer (score 38):

If you use Java 7+, this pattern should work (`X` is for the ISO 8601 time zone):

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
```

Comment: This is very nice to know. I'm still stuck with java 1.6- :(

Comment: Same here about Java 6, but thanks for noting this.

Comment: The correct pattern for the date example of this question should probably be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" (i.e., just one 'X').

Comment: @PNS You are right - amended.

Comment: If only one `X` is used, you'll get a truncated time zone, e.g.,

`2014-03-03-T16:00:00-08`. 

From my reading of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html (and testing), you want `XXX` in order to get a properly formatted time zone (at least in terms of what the OP points to, specifically section 3.2.7.3), e.g., `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"`, which gives you

`2014-03-03-T16:00:00-08:00`.

Note the colon-separated time zone info.

Answer (score 11):

Hmmm the date format looks like XML datetime datatype format? If it is XML datetime datatype format you can use [javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html) to create `XMLGregorianCalendar`

```
DatatypeFactory
  .newInstance()
  .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2012-05-15T07:08:09+03:00");
```

The above call returns instance of `XMLGregorianCalendar` you can use the object to convert to  other Java datetime objects like `GregorianCalendar`.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no workaround to make `SimpleDateFormat` understand this format without preprocessing the string (for example by removing the `:` from the string). (edit: except if you're using Java 7 or newer as noted by assylias).

It looks like you're trying to parse strings in the standard XML format for dates and times (ISO 8601). I would recommend using the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library which has [support for this format](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_iso.html).

If you can't or don't want to use Joda Time for some reason, then you can use classes from the package `javax.xml.datatype` to parse and format timestamps in this format. For example:

```
DatatypeFactory factory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();

// Parses a string in ISO 8601 format to an XMLGregorianCalendar
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = factory.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2012-05-16T10:39:00+03:00");

// Convert it to a regular java.util.Calendar
Calendar cal = xmlCal.toGregorianCalendar();
```

Comment: JodaTime does not support all the patterns that Java SimpleDateFormat class supports.

Comment: @PNS Yes but your were asking specifically about the ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Sure, I just pointed out the limitation. Otherwise, JodaTime would probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to Use the Joda's

```
org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat
```

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

use Apache commons DateUtils with possible patterns.
Ex:

```
private static final String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[] {
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", "yyyy-MM-ddz", "yyyy-MM-ddZ" };


    public Date parse(String date) {

        Date parsedDate = null;
        try {
            parsedDate = DateUtils.parseDate(date, DATE_FORMATS);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error("dates should be in valid format" + e);
            return null;
        }
               return parsedDate;
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure whether this will work for you or not.
But here the code I have tried while converting date from one timezone to another timezone.
May some part of the code can help you.

```
public Date convertToUserTimezone(long dateToConvert, String timezoneOffset){
        java.text.DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM);/*new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");*/
        // java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(new
        // SimpleTimeZone(0, "GMT+05:30"));
        TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"+timezoneOffset);


        format.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
        java.util.Date date1 = new Date(format.format(new Date(dateToConvert)));

        return date1;
    }
```

Hope this helps you.
Cheers. :)

Comment: I was after something simpler, but thanks for the effort. :-)

Answer (score 1):

With regards to SimpleDateFormat you have already mentioned the format patterns that are available and they are defined in: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

If you want to do more with your Date then GregorianCalendar gives you more options, e.g.:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8").getID());
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(zone);
calendar.setTime(new Date(SomeDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
Date date = df.parse(stringDate.replaceAll("\\+", "GMT+"));
```

Comment: Sure, but I was wondering whether it can be done without preprocessing.