# Parsing Java dates with truncated timezone information

Tags: java, regex, date, date-format, simpledateformat

Consider the following date string

- `2012-10-01 01:02:03.004+0500`

This is recognized in Java using the following `SimpleDateFormat` pattern:

- `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

If, however, the timezone information above is truncated to 2 digits, i.e. like

- `2012-10-01 01:02:03.004+05`

the date string does not comply to any valid format, so there is no `SimpleDateFormat` pattern that could be used in order to correctly parse it.

Is there any workaround for parsing the truncated timezone correctly **without string preprocessing**?

If not, which regular expression would be optimal for that preprocessing to be done for a **large number** of such date strings **in 1 round**, e.g. using a `replaceFirst()` call, as in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614771/java-simpledateformat-pattern-for-w3c-xml-dates-with-timezone)?

Comment: That's a `SimpleDateFormat`pattern, not a `DateFormat` pattern. Try subclassing `SimpleDateFormat` to append `00` when needed.

Comment: You are right in both suggestions. The subclassing approach seems the most plausible at this point, along the lines of the similar question I linked to above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know a good solution without string preprocessing, but if `replaceFirst` is acceptable, you can use this code snippet:

```
dateStr.replaceFirst("(?<=[+-]\\d\\d)$", "00")
```

This code appends two zeros to strings ending in `<plus|minus><digit><digit>` ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/A5Zj6)).

Comment: The timezone can start with a `<minus>` too.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but I am concerned about performance. You are right in that there seems to be no ideal solution. Your proposal does work. You may want to change \\d\\d into \\d{2}, for elegance. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @PNS On the point of `\\d{2}`, programmers often count "zero, one, two, many", and I'm one of them. Besides, there may only be so much "elegance" when we are talking regular expressions ;-)

Comment: I prefer elegance, but no worries. It will do just fine! :-)