# Java SimpleDateFormat Timezone offset with minute separated by colon

Tags: java, simpledateformat

How can I get my date formatted as `2012-11-25T23:50:56.193+01:00` using `SimpleDateFormat`?
If I use `Z` in the format like

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ`

then it shows

`2013-03-06T11:49:05.490+0100`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can get the timezone offset formatted like `+01:00` with the *SimpleDateFormat* in **Java 7** (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`), or with the **Joda**'s *DateTimeFormat* (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`).

Comment: is there a way for older javas without joda?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040143/generic-support-for-iso-8601-format-in-java-6

Comment: I believe the format is with "HH" i.e. yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX; as 'hh' will produce 00-12 and 'HH' 00-23.  Also, from the other SO question linked.

Comment: Yes! This is answer and helped me figure out my problem of setting GMT like -05:00 and not -0500.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat that has been described in the answer is described on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for reference.

Comment: Note: Make sure you check this condition: it will only work for API 24+ https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 4):

Here’s the 2017 answer. If there is any way you can (which there is), throw the outdated classes like `SimpleDateFormat` overboard and use the modern and more convenient classes in [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). In particular, the desired format, `2012-11-25T23:50:56.193+01:00` complies with ISO-8601 and therefore comes out of the box with the newer classes, just use `OffsetDateTime.toString()`:

```
    OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(time.toString());
```

This prints something like

```
2017-05-10T16:14:20.407+02:00
```

One thing you may or may not want to be aware of, though, it prints as many groups of 3 decimals on the seconds as it takes to print the precision in the `OffsetDateTime` object. Apparently on my computer “now” comes with a precision of milliseconds (seconds with three decimals).

If you have an oldfashioned `Date` object, for example, you got it from a call to some legacy method, I recommend the first thing you do is convert it to `Instant`, which is one of the modern classes. From there you can easily other conversions depending on your requirements:

```
    Date now = new Date();
    OffsetDateTime time = now.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(time.toString());
```

I am really doing more conversions than necessary. `atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())` produced a `ZonedDateTime`, and its `toString()` will not always give you the format you said you wanted; but it can easily be formatted into it:

```
    ZonedDateTime time = now.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
```