# Java date offset format issue?

Tags: java

My date format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`, which is producing the date :

```
2013-10-08T12:14:39.721+0100
```

But I need the date to be :

```
2013-10-08T12:14:39.721+01:00
```

what date format will generate the offset with a colon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```

Have a look at the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info.

**P.S:-** As my friend *@Thomas* mentioned, this will work only with *Java 7* and above.

Comment: Just a note here that got me: this works for Java 7+.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you can use [R.J. solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19246464/1060037) which will work for JDK 7. You can also implement the same using [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) as below

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
String str = fmt.print(dt);
System.out.println(str);
```

which outputs,

```
2013-10-08T20:36:19.802+09:00
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2013-10-08T12:14:39.721+01:00" )
              .toString()
```

> 2013-10-08T12:14:39.721+01:00

## java.time

Use the modern java.time classes that supplant the troublesome legacy date-time classes.

Your desired output format happens to be the default of [`OffsetDateTime::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--) method.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2013-10-08T12:14:39.721+01:00" ) ;
String output = odt.toString() ;
```

> output: 2013-10-08T12:14:39.721+01:00

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/pxTgva).

By the way, in my experience is indeed best to format your offset-from-UTC as you asked in your Question: **with the colon, with padding zero, and with both hours and minutes**. While the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard and others technically allow variations, I have found some libraries and protocols expect only the fully expanded format. So use `+05:00` rather than `+05` or `+5:00` or `+0500`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing it simply to that format doesn't work? Or you're unable to change the date format?
Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSXXX");
```

It should return the last part separated by a colon.

See: [Java SimpleDateFormat Timezone offset with minute separated by colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245307/java-simpledateformat-timezone-offset-with-minute-seperated-my-colon)