# SimpleDateFormat pattern query

Tags: java, simpledateformat

What is the pattern for `SimpleDateFormat` that produces strings that look like

> 2013-11-22T14:30:03.2148+02:00

?

Comment: Did you 1) try anything 2) check the docs before posting this question?

Comment: Yes. My main problem is with the time zone component: neither 'z' nor 'Z' created 02:00

Comment: See here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245307/java-simpledateformat-timezone-offset-with-minute-seperated-by-colon

Comment: Explain the format you want for others its difficult to interpret the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chek [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You will find:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

Comment: This does not work for JDK <= 6. Right?

Comment: @peter.petrov According to [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), in JDK5 is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`.

Comment: This (with the Z) is not doing 100% what the OP wants. This gives: "2014-01-09T06:47:19.078-0500" while OP wants: "2014-01-09T06:47:19.0782-05:00". I am not sure how it can be done with JDK <= 6.

Comment: I know how. Migrate to JDK7.

Comment: Fortunately I am using Java7 so this answer is good enough for me. In fact, yesterday's comment to the question by @peter.petrov had reference to another question with the same answer. Thanks everyone who tried to help