# Unparseable date: "2013-07-11T13:41:22.000Z" (at offset 23)

Tags: java

Can anybody tell me why in the world I got this exception?

> 08-28 08:47:05.246: D/DateParser(4238): String received for parsing is
>   2013-08-05T12:13:49.000Z

```
private final static String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";


public static Date parseDate(String stringToParse) {
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN).parse(stringToParse);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Logger.logError(TAG, e);
        }
        return null;
    }

08-28 08:47:05.246: E/DateParser(4238): Exception: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-08-05T12:13:49.000Z" (at offset 23)
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

try using

```
String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

The `Z` at the end is usually the timezone offset.  If you you don't need it maybe you can drop it on both sides.

Answer (score 12):

Use `X` instead of `Z` at the end of the format string:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX
```

to parse ISO-8601 format timezone offsets.

(Only works if you use Java 7. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040143/generic-support-for-iso-8601-format-in-java-6)).

Answer (score 2):

The `Z` in your time string is not a valid timezone identifier, but the time format you specified expects a time zone identifier there. More specifically, it expects a [RFC 822 timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) identifier, which is usually 4 digits long.

Answer (score 0):

From java-8 you can directly use `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant` if it is in [ISO_INSTANT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2013-08-05T12:13:49.000Z")

Instant.parse("2013-08-05T12:13:49.000Z")
```