# Java String to DateTime

Tags: java, datetime

I have a string from a json response:

```
start: "2013-09-18T20:40:00+0000",
end: "2013-09-18T21:39:00+0000",
```

How do i convert this string to a java DateTime Object?

i have tried using the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
start = sdf.parse("2013-09-18T20:40:00+0000");
```

but with this i can only create a Date Object. But the time binded in the String is kinda essential.

Any Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Date` also has time information.

Comment: Ok, but still i need it to be a DateTime Object :)

Comment: Java has no `DateTime` class. Use  `Date`.

Comment: Are you talking about java api or the joda time api?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Similar to [Generic support for ISO 8601 format in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040143/generic-support-for-iso-8601-format-in-java-6).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create Joda [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object from the Java [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object, since Java does not have a `DateTime` class.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(start.getTime());
```

---

Though the `Date` class of Java holds the time information as well(that's what you need in the first place), I suggest you to use a `Calendar` instead of the `Date` class of Java.

```
Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
myCal.setTime(date);
```

Have a look at the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) docs for more info on how you can use it more effectively.

---

Things have changed and now even Java (Java 8 to be precise), has a [LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [ZonedDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. For conversions, you can have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19726814/2024761)(posting an excerpt from there).

Given: `Date date = [some date]`

**(1) LocalDateTime << Instant<< Date**

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

**(2) Date << Instant << LocalDateTime**

```
Instant instant = ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: +1 for the use of Joda - it's a far better date implementation as the basic Java one

Comment: @RJ Your link points to the wrong `Date`, it's `java.util.Date`, not `java.sql.Date` :)

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong type to use here. You would be throwing away valuable time zone or offset-from-UTC information. Use `ZonedDateTime` when you want to view an `Instant` in another region’s wall-clock time.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need a `DateTime` object. [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) stores the time too.

```
int hours = start.getHours(); //returns the hours
int minutes = start.getMinutes(); //returns the minutes
int seconds = start.getSeconds(); //returns the seconds
```

---

As R.J says, these methods are deprecated, so you can use the [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) class:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse("2013-09-18T20:40:00+0000"));
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR); //returns the hour
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE); //returns the minute
int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND); //returns the second
```

**Note:** on my end, `sdf.parse("2013-09-18T20:40:00+0000")` fires a

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-09-18T20:40:00+0000"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:16)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DateTimeFormatter](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
DateTime time = format.parseDateTime("2013-09-18T20:40:00+0000");
```

Comment: This support is there from Android O onwards

Comment: No, @PrasadGKulkarni, it’s Joda-Time, an external library that works fine with earlier Android versions too.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    String startStr = "2013-09-18T20:40:00+0000";
    OffsetDateTime start = OffsetDateTime.parse(startStr, isoFormatter);
    System.out.println(start);
```

Output is:

> 2013-09-18T20:40Z

I was using this formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter isoFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .appendOffset("+HHMM", "+0000")
        .toFormatter();
```

If by a `DateTime` object you meant `org.joda.time.Datetime`, please read this quote from the Joda-Time homepage (boldface is original):

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this
> project.**

The `SimpleDateFormat` class that you tried to use in the question is a notorious troublemaker of a class and long outdated. Under no circumstances use it. Ever.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Joda-Time - Home](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score -1):

Have you try this?

```
Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2013-09-18T20:40:00+0000".replace("T"," ").substring(0,19));
```

Comment: Unnecessary replace function