# Why can't OffsetDateTime parse '2016-08-24T18:38:05.507+0000' in Java 8

Tags: java, date, java-time, datetime-parsing, offsetdatetime

The expression

`OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-08-24T18:38:05.507+0000")`

results in the following error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-08-24T18:38:05.507+0000' could not be parsed at index 23

On the other hand,

`OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-08-24T18:38:05.507+00:00")`

works as expected.

[DateTimeFormatter's doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) mentions zone offsets without colons as examples.  What am I doing wrong?  I'd rather not mangle my date string to appease Java.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm using `OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString.replaceFirst("\\+(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "+$1:$2"))`

Comment: I am immodest enough to recommend [my own answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66232081/5772882).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling the following method.

```
public static OffsetDateTime parse(CharSequence text) {
    return parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
}
```

It uses uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` as `DateTimeFormatter` which, as stated in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), does the following:

> The ISO date-time formatter that formats or parses a date-time with an offset, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00'.

If you want to parse a date with a different format as in `2016-08-24T18:38:05.507+0000` you should use `OffsetDateTime#parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter)`. The following code should solve your problem:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-08-24T18:38:05.507+0000", formatter);
```

Comment: Mine is not working, it is really taking me in cycles

Answer (score 5):

### Update

Thanks to Ole V.V. for suggesting this simpler pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                        .appendPattern("[XXX][XX][X]")
                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

The original answer is still useful if the units (e.g. month, day, hour etc.) can be in single-digit or double-digit. This alternative pattern will fail in case units are in single-digit.

### Original answer

The solution is to use a `DateTimeFormatter` with optional patterns. The `DateTimeFormatter` allows us to specify optional patterns in the square bracket.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "u-M-d'T'H:m:s[.[SSSSSSSSS][SSSSSSSS][SSSSSSS][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][SS][S]][XXX][XX][X]",
                Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                "2021-07-22T20:10:15+0000",
                "2021-07-22T20:10:15+00:00",
                "2021-07-22T20:10:15+00",
                "2021-07-22T20:10:15.123456789+0000",
                "2021-07-22T20:10:15.12345678+0000",
                "2021-07-22T20:10:15.123+0000",
                "2021-07-22T20:10:15.1+0000"                
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(s, dtf)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-07-22T20:10:15Z
2021-07-22T20:10:15Z
2021-07-22T20:10:15Z
2021-07-22T20:10:15.123456789Z
2021-07-22T20:10:15.123456780Z
2021-07-22T20:10:15.123Z
2021-07-22T20:10:15.100Z
```

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>Check the [documentation page of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for the complete list of pattern letters.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Although `DateTimeFormatter`'s pattern language does not provide a code for zone offsets that fail to accommodate your no-colon form, that does not imply that the pre-defined instances that handle zone offsets accept the no-colon form.  The one-arg version of `OffsetDateTime.parse()` specifies that it uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` as its formatter, and that formatter's docs specify that it supports three formats, as described in [the docs of ZoneOffset.getId()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#getId--).  None of those formats (which are drawn from ISO-8601) is consistent with your no-colon form.

But not to worry: just use the two-arg from of `OffsetDateTime.parse()`, providing an appropriate formatter.  That's a bit less convenient, but quite doable.

Answer (score 2):

Paypal incorrectly sends the offsets as `+0000` which is actually contradicting their spec https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/ that says it has to be in an [Internet date/time format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339#section-5.6) where the offset is written as

```
 time-numoffset  = ("+" / "-") time-hour ":" time-minute
```

The `:` is required.

To work around this, a custom date time formatter should be created, but avoid using the simple pattern like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` because it will fail if milliseconds suddenly appear in the output.

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter PAYPAL_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    .parseLenient()
    .appendPattern("Z")
    .parseStrict()
    .toFormatter();
```

This is one way of doing it, but it has a flaw in that when Paypal corrects their output it won't be able to parse the `:` offset correctly.

Also Paypal does not support nanos so you should also do `.truncatedTo(SECONDS)` before sending it to their APIs

Answer (score 1):

The default format is expected to be `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` defined with the following value for the zone offset:

```
static final OffsetIdPrinterParser INSTANCE_ID_Z = new OffsetIdPrinterParser("+HH:MM:ss", "Z");
```