# Converting string date time with +0000 To instant

Tags: java, java-time, timezone-offset, datetimeformatter, java.time.instant

How do I convert the datetime that is passed as string 2018-08-10T18:25:00.000+0000 to a Instant? I tried the below and it did not work.

```
 public static Instant toInstant(final String timeStr) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(timeStr)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date time value passed [" + timeStr + "]");
    }

    try {
        return LocalDate.parse(timeStr).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(timeStr).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            try {
                return ZonedDateTime.parse(timeStr).toInstant();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                try {
                    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    return LocalDateTime.parse(timeStr, formatter).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
                } catch (Exception e3) {
                    try {
                        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                        return LocalDateTime.parse(timeStr, formatter).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
                    } catch (Exception e4) {
                        try {
                            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
                            return LocalDateTime.parse(timeStr, formatter).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
                        } catch (Exception e5) {
                        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
                            return LocalDateTime.parse(timeStr, formatter).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
                        } finally {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect date time value passed [" + timeStr + "]");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `OffsetDateTime.parse(...).toInstant()`? Why the many tries?

Comment: "2018-08-10T18:25:00.000+0000" is not ISO-conformant, but "2018-08-10T18:25:00.000+00:00" is. (Note the added colon.) If you use the correct format, you can use `Instant instant = Instant.parse("2018-08-10T18:25:00.000+00:00");`

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose `Instant.parse` is even shorter.

Comment: @k314159 Indeed the string conforms to ISO 8601. Funnily the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse(CharSequence)` does not accept it. See for example [Why can't OffsetDateTime parse '2016-08-24T18:38:05.507+0000' in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133828/why-cant-offsetdatetime-parse-2016-08-24t183805-5070000-in-java-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trouble is here:

```
        } finally {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect date time value passed [" + timeStr + "]");
        }
```

Your parsing is successful in these lines (but may give an incorrect result):

```
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
            return LocalDateTime.parse(timeStr, formatter).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

After you have successfully parsed your string, in your `finally` block you are throwing an exception. So the caller does not receive the result and instead gets an exception and will have to think that parsing or conversion failed.

An incorrect result? Your parsing into `LocalDateTime` throws away the UTC offset in the string, `+0000`. Next your conversion to `Instant` assumes UTC, which in this case happens to agree with the string. If the offset in the string had been anyting else than `+0000` (for example, `+0100`), you will get an incorrect `Instant`.

The other answers show correct ways of converting your string to `Instant`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OffsetDateTime` with `DateTimeFormatter`. Something like this,

```
public static Instant toInstant(final String timeStr) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(timeStr, formatter);
    return dateTime.toInstant();
}
```

Comment: That’s not much different from what the OP is already trying.

Answer (score 1):

Your string, `2018-08-10T18:25:00.000+0000` has a timezone offset of `+0000` hours and therefore, you should parse it to `OffsetDateTime` which can be converted into `Instant`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-08-10T18:25:00.000+0000", dtf);
        Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2018-08-10T18:25:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3KNaa1)

The `DateTimeFormatter` used in the above solution will work only for a fixed number of digits specified in the pattern e.g. only 3 digits in the fraction-of-second. A better `DateTimeFormatter` can be built using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` as shown in the following demo:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                                .appendPattern("Z")
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-08-10T18:25:00.000+0000", dtf);
        Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2018-08-10T18:25:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MZNYhe)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>