# Unparseable date exception, can't find pattern for 2014-11-28T13:46:23-08:00

Tags: java, android, parsing, java.util.date

I'm trying to parse `2014-11-28T13:46:23-08:00` to a `java.util.Date`

For the simpledateformat so far I've tried:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

`yyyy-MM-dd` works but I need at-least precision to the minute.

What pattern should I be using to parse this date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the standard ISO-8601 date format.  Try:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

This is very close to the first format you tried, with the addition of "Z".  That character is for the UTC offset.

Comment: According to the description it should IMO be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` - `Z` is for `-0800`, while `XXX` is for `-08:00`. See examples at the end of the [`SimpleDateFormat` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) EDIT: `X` is apparently a Java7+ thing http://stackoverflow.com/a/10614978/995891