# Convert XMLSchema datetime datatype literal into Java SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, xml, datetime, xmlschemaset

I'm trying to convert the following XMLSchema datetime datatype literal

```
   "~@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime 2015-04-18T07:52:53.653"
```

into Java datetime object. I tried different alternatives including the one presented in [Java SimpleDateFormat pattern for W3C XML dates with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614771/java-simpledateformat-pattern-for-w3c-xml-dates-with-timezone), but never succeeded. Also tried the issue described in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/HermannSW/entry/java_simpledateformat_vs_xs_datetime26?lang=en, but again unsuccessful. Any solution?

Comment: call `s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1)`, and parse the result?

Comment: with SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")?

Comment: Yes, that seems like the right pattern.

Comment: I tried that and got IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: Post your code. I just tested it, and it works fine here.

Comment: `String s1 ="~@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime 2015-04-18T07:52:53.653"; String part = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1); SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");System.out.println(fmt.format(part));`

Comment: You're trying to format a String. That doesn't make sense. `format()` takes a Date, and produces a String. `parse()` takes a String, and produces a Date.

Comment: You're right @JBNizet I mixed the notions. I used parse() and it gave me the result. Thank you